# Restrict Internet with Active Directory?

Tags: internet, active-directory, restrictions

What's the best way (with Active Directory or Group Policy) to restrict Internet Access to computers or users, and avoid them to change that settings without an admin password?

Cheers

Comment: What exactly are you trying to restrict? Are you trying to block all access to the Internet?

Comment: Do you users have admin right on their own computers?

Comment: For example in the university or in some companies some computers are allowed to browse the Internet and some other not, at least that the admin enables it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use group policy and force a fake proxy, localhost for example. something like this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5156.how-to-force-proxy-settings-via-group-policy.aspx